# How to find categories based on text string on Wordpress search form

Tags: php, wordpress

How to find categories based on text string on Wordpress search form
I'm trying to find a way to find posts with specific categories. I can't seem to get the behavior working correctly though.

On my functions.php file, I have this code:

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        if ( isset($_GET['categoriesRB']) && !empty($_GET['s']) ) {
            $query->set( 'category_name', $_GET['s'] );
        } else {
            //...
        }

        return $query;
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','filter_search');
```

where 'categoriesRB' is a radio button in the search form that signifies the query is a category. I'm not getting the correct results that I'm expecting though.

When I turn on 'categoriesRB', and leave the search form blank, I'm getting all the results from the search page, not just the categories that I'm looking for. When i add in the search term, I'm getting "Results Not Found."

Comment: I've formatted your code for you.  I'd highly recommend getting into that habit - will make your life far easier in the future.

Comment: Also, rather than `$_GET['s']  != ''`, I'd recommend `! empty($_GET['s'])` - your code may throw undefined index notices, whereas `! empty` will not, and will accomplish the same thing you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Lastly - you need to leverage a taxonomy query.  "Categories" per-se won't show up in a search result, I'm assuming you're actually trying to get _posts within_ the category.  If so, this is a start for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207499/using-pre-get-posts-to-filter-posts

Comment: Good points, I implemented this !empty change on my local project and edited the post. Will look into the taxonomy query to see if it helps me solve the issue. What I'm trying to do is searching for a term (e.g. 'recipes' that serve as a 'category' and look up all posts that have the category 'recipes') which seems to be in line with what you just stated.